# Word for a statement that's obvious

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember "the" word which is defined as being a statement said in public which is so obvious that it is embarrassing for everyone to have to listen to. For example: if someone enters a house saying that it's raining outside, which can be clearly seen through a window by everyone inside the house, then this statement is so obvious that it is, let's just say, a statement which is not so intelligent a statement for someone to make - such as the statement I just made. HA

Comment: Self-evident might be it.

Comment: I think Homer said it best - [Doh!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doh)

Comment: @bib Was that from *The Iliad* or *The Odyssey*?

Comment: @deadrat I think it was *The Idiocy*.

Comment: There should be at least two words.  One to conversation. The comment about the rain is obviously conversational.  A second to describe such a statement that embarrasses.  A layman in a group of professionals might make such a statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you "state the obvious", it's a **truism**

- From wikipedia: A truism is a claim that is so obvious or self-evident as to be hardly worth mentioning.

In some cases, a "self-evident statement" may be a **platitude** (or less approriate in the question context, a "cliché").

- From wikipedia: A platitude is a trite, meaningless, or prosaic statement, generally directed at quelling social, emotional, or cognitive unease. The word derives from plat, French word for "flat." Platitudes are geared towards presenting a shallow, unifying wisdom over a difficult topic. However, they are too overused and general to be anything more than undirected statements with ultimately little meaningful contribution towards a solution.

Comment: The OED gives platitude as  ' "Commonplaceness"; a commonplace remark, esp one solemnly delivered', eg: 'you can lead a horse to water but you can't make it drink'

Answer (score 0):

If the statement asserts the same thing in two different ways, such that it cannot possibly be contradicted, then it is a *tautology*.  Eg, "Either it will rain tomorrow or it won't rain."

Answer (score 0):

I like glaringly, palpably, conspicuously, unmistakably, and inanely for proceeding the word "obvious" in this case.

A statement of the obvious is also called a truism and/or self-evident.

The speaker or statement can be inane or asinine. They are two of my favorites. (<:

Answer (score -2):

try 'axiomatic' - although this is not entirely correct.

You enter the house soaking wet and say, ironically "Of course, it is axiomatic that it rains on 1st June".

The most obvious is 'obviously' or you could use 'indisputably':

"You're very wet."
"Obviously, it's pouring with rain."

or "It is indisputably raining cats & dogs."